# Install netbeans 8.2 on Mac os high sierra / Installer netbeans 8.2 on mac os high sierra

Tags: java, macos, netbeans, java-8, java-11

I'm encountering a problem by trying to use NetBeans 8.2 under Mac Os High Sierra. I'm trying to create a new project but nothing happens.

So after few search over the web I seem to understand that my problem is my actual version of Java JDK which is 11.0.

Unfortunately I dont know how to switch my actual version to an earlier one JDK 8.0 which seems to be the one to use for netbean 8.2 ! :/

If anyone knows how to help me I would be really greatful ! :P

Maxime Prieur

Answer (score 0):

There are two steps involved in getting NetBeans 8.2 to work:

1. Download and install JDK 1.8 if it is not already on your machine:

   - [This answer describes how to do that](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/334385) for openjdk 1.8 on High Sierra.
   - Alternatively, [you can download Oracle JDK 1.8](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html). The [installation instructions are here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/install_overview.html).
2. Once JDK 1.8 is installed, update the file **netbeans.conf**:

   - Locate file **netbeans.conf** within the **etc** directory under the NetBeans installation directory.
   - It is a text file containing name/value property pairs. Open it in any text editor.
   - One of the properties it might specify is the path to the default JDK to be used via property **netbeans_jdkhome**. Therefore locate the line containing the text ***netbeans_jdkhome***.
   - If line is commented by starting with the **#** character then delete that character.
   - In the unlikely event that the property does not exist in the file at all, just insert it at the end of the file.
   - The property's value should be the path to your JDK 1.8 installation.
   - In my NetBeans 8.2 installation my entry looks like this `netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_181"`, though obviously your path will be different.
   - Save your change to **netbeans.conf** and restart Netbeans. Your issue should be resolved.

Alternatively, if you would prefer to use JDK 11, you could take a completely different approach:

- [Download and install Apache NetBeans 10.0](http://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb100/nb100.html) which supports JDK 11.
- Since you already have JDK 11 installed, NetBeans should work immediately.

Notes:

- With NetBeans 10.0, individual projects can be configured to use JDK 8, 9, 10 or 11, provided that:

  - The corresponding JDK is installed on your machine.
  - The corresponding JDK is also added as a **Java Platform** within NetBeans (using **Tools > Java Platforms > Add Platform...**).
- On NetBeans 8.2 you cannot use any JDK version > 8.
- You can safely install both NetBeans 8.2 and NetBeans 10.0, and even run both instances concurrently. They do not impact each other in any way, though obviously you should not open a project in both instances of NetBeans at the same time.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your reponse! All work perfectly now ! :)