# NetBeans 8.2 installed and Issue with Services

Tags: netbeans-8, netbeans-8.2

Installed Netbeans 8.2 and when i click Windows->Service and then it went to Blank and display Nothing. No errors too.

Tried to restart the System and Downloaded options All and JEE however nothing worked.

NA

NA

Comment: There is not nearly enough information in this question for it to be resolved. In particular, show the output from the NetBeans log (**View -> IDE Log**). Also see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: WARNING [org.netbeans.modules.profiler.NetBeansProfiler]: Failed to initialize the Profiler engine: Problem with a required JFluid installation directory or file C:/Program Files/NetBeans 8.2/profiler/lib/deployed/UNSUPPORTED_JDK/windows-amd64                                            I think it is deployed wuth UNSUPPORTED JDK.     How to install with Supported JDK ? Please share steps. Thanks

Comment: NetBeans 8.2 does not support the use of any Java version > 8 (i.e. > JDK 1.8). Assuming that is your problem, the cleanest approach to resolve it is probably: [1] Uninstall NetBeans 8.2. [2] Optionally, uninstall any Java version > 8 on your machine that you don't need. [3] Ensure that Java 8 is installed on your machine. [4] Reinstall NetBeans 8.2, using Java 8. That sounds like a lot of work, but it shouldn't take long.

Comment: Alternatively, if Java 8 is already on your machine, edit NetBeans file **etc/netbeans.conf** to set Java 8 as the default version of Java to be used. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54156214/2985643 for full details on how to do that.

Comment: @skomisa It Worked. I used JDK 1.8 and used jdk1.8 path during installation.Thank you So much.