# Change netbeans 8.2 JDK MacOS High Sierra

Tags: java, macos, netbeans

At first, I installed the latest version of netbeans which is netbeans 12. But then I uninstalled because I can't seem to find what I needed for my school project. So I installed the version that they told me to install. I installed netbeans 8.2 already, the app can be opened but can't do anything at all. After I searched I found out it's a jdk version problem but after I tried different question and answer in SO I can't seem to find the answer. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54155682/install-netbeans-8-2-on-mac-os-high-sierra-installer-netbeans-8-2-on-mac-os-hi) for example, doesn't work because I can't seem to find the *netbeans.conf* file.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please update it to clarify the precise problem to be solved, and also specify: [1] Which version(s) of NetBeans are installed on your machine? [2] Which specific version of NetBeans do you want to be using? [3] Which JDK version(s) are installed on your machine? [4] What specific JDK version do you want to be using? Also note that **netbeans.conf** resides in the **etc** directory,and if it is not there then there is a problem with your NetBeans installation.

Comment: I thought I already clarify most of that? 1. 8.2 2. 8.2 3. 12 4. 8

Comment: And yes I can't find the conf file in there

Comment: [1] Please (always) update the question with new information rather than posting it in comments. [2] Your problem is that you are trying to use JDK 12 with NetBeans 8.2, which does not support any JDK > 1.8. That just won't work. [3] The fix is to uninstall JDK 12, install JDK 8 and try NetBeans 8.2 again. [4] I just verified that NB 8.2 won't start without **netbeans.conf** so please check again - it has to be there. [5] An alternative approach is to use NetBeans 11.2 with JDK 13, which works fine. You don't need to uninstall any existing software to try that.